# Can't get VS intellisense to find CommaDelimitedStringCollection

Tags: c#, namespaces, intellisense

VS2015 CE here battling to get IntelliSense (C#) to show the collection in subject.

This is my "using" list:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using createsend_dotnet;
```

You would think it should find it somewhere, wouldn't you? :)
Apparently that is not so though. Before someone tells me that it's the wrong
way to do it, trust me, it's perfectly OK. What I am trying to do here is to get a number of comma-separated permissions to be passed along to an OAUTH API call. 
Hence, I just need one line and that class is perfect.

Comment: Did you add a reference to System.configuration in your project?

Comment: I was going to reply "Yes, of course, why would a Windows Forms C# project add that using to a form without adding the reference to the proj.." but then I went looking. GROAN.

Comment: This things happens ;)

Comment: Yes, especially if you do not use VS as your main dev environment. Is it just me thinking that this is insane? What exactly is the point of that?

Comment: Well yeah, it's a strange behaviour sometimes happen with some namespaces. I think it has to do with the namespace being split in several dll's.

Comment: @Pikoh I think you should post your comment as reply, so that I can accept it as a solution because, well, it is :)

Comment: I've added it as a solution, so others looking for it may find it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add a reference to System.configuration.  I believe this behavior with some namespaces has to do with the namespace being split in several dll's.